# What language, culture, traditions etc, gives their son only the father family names and their daughters the mother family names?

Tags: genealogy, brazil, surname

I'm sorry, if this is not the right place to ask this question. I'm currently doing research in genealogy, and I have encountered a pattern: if you go back enough generations, the luso-hispanic way of family names (name [dads family name] [moms family name] disappear and give away a system that makes:
Son: name + dads two family names.
Daughter: name + moms two family

My family came from rural Brazil (specifically Bahia), thank you for your attention!

P.S: I asked this in linguistics, but someone said it fitted more here.

Comment: There is a [Genealogy & Family History](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/) site which might be better focused on this type of question.

Comment: @SteveBird Since the guy said there wasn't a genealogy stackexhange site i didn't look it up, thank you though.

Comment: Kind of intrigued by this question. Sounds like you think there may be an indigenous Brazillian culture that this came from, and after reading what you know, I'm thinking the same thing.

Comment: Consider reading through the [WIkipedia page on Lustophone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_name). It looks to me like indeed the surname naming custom in Brazil has changed greatly in the last 100 years.

Comment: @T.E.D. Doesn't seem like it to me, the indigenous population on the region is very small, my family has never even met with an native

Comment: In Spain and Portugal from 1200 to c. 1800 there weren't clear rules for the family names. I.e, Don Íñigo López de Mendoza (1398-1458) and Catalina Suárez de Figueroa had the following children: Diego Hurtado de Mendoza, Íñigo López de Mendoza, Lorenzo Suárez de Figueroa, Pedro González de Mendoza, Pedro Hurtado de Mendoza, Juan Hurtado de Mendoza, Pedro Lasso de la Vega, Mencía de Mendoza, María de Mendoza and Leonor de la Vega. They invented family names for some of them, they mixed father's and mother's and they even brought back a "de la Vega", the family name of Catalina's mother.

Comment: @CarlosMartin yeah, but this is seen even in 20th century!

Comment: @brunothedev But in the 20th century it could be from the Portuguese (relatively recent) tradition of putting the mother's last name first and the father's second. And for the men, the mother's last name is (usually) ignored when writing their name whereas women changed their second last name when they got married (adopting their husband second last name), so their first last name (their mother's) was invariable through all their lives and never ignored.